# Array position by object value

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, sorting, object

I want to make a function that sorts array by the value of the specific key.

I will put example.

```js
[{ text: 'hi', author: 'Boy' },
{ text: 'how are you', author: 'Boy' },
{ text: 'I\'m good', author: 'Boy' },
{ text: 'hello', author: 'Girl' },
{ text: 'Bye', author: 'Boy' }]
```

In the above array, 'Girl' author is more than 'Boy' author so it should return following array

```js
[{ text: 'hello', author: 'Girl' },
{ text: 'hi', author: 'Boy' },
{ text: 'how are you', author: 'Boy' },
{ text: 'I\'m good', author: 'Boy' },
{ text: 'Bye', author: 'Boy' }]
```

Second example:

```js
[{ text: 'hi', author: 'Boy' },
{ text: 'hola', author: 'Mom' },
{ text: 'how are you', author: 'Boy' },
{ text: 'I\'m good', author: 'Boy' },
{ text: 'hello', author: 'Girl' },
{ text: 'eat this', author: 'Mom' },
{ text: 'Bye', author: 'Boy' }]
```

Second result:

```js
[{ text: 'hello', author: 'Girl' },
{ text: 'hola', author: 'Mom' },
{ text: 'eat this', author: 'Mom' },
{ text: 'hi', author: 'Boy' },
{ text: 'how are you', author: 'Boy' },
{ text: 'I\'m good', author: 'Boy' },
{ text: 'Bye', author: 'Boy' }]
```

Last example:

```js
const data = [
  { text: 'hi', author: 'Boy' },
  { text: 'hola', author: 'Mom' },
  { text: 'hola', author: 'Mom' },
  { text: 'hola', author: 'Mom' },
  { text: 'how are you', author: 'Boy' },
  { text: "I'm good", author: 'Boy' },
  { text: 'hello', author: 'Girl' },
  { text: 'eat this', author: 'Mom' },
  { text: 'Bye', author: 'Boy' }
]
```

Last Result ( I don't care if Boy is first or Mom is first

```js
const data = [
  { text: 'hello', author: 'Girl' },
  { text: 'hola', author: 'Mom' },
  { text: 'hola', author: 'Mom' },
  { text: 'hola', author: 'Mom' },
  { text: 'eat this', author: 'Mom' },
  { text: 'hi', author: 'Boy' },
  { text: 'how are you', author: 'Boy' },
  { text: "I'm good", author: 'Boy' },
  { text: 'Bye', author: 'Boy' }
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value)

Comment: do you want to sort by count of  the authors?

Comment: can you clarify a bit? what will be the output of this input `[{ text: 'hi', author: 'Boy' },
{ text: 'hola', author: 'Mom' },
{ text: 'how are you', author: 'Boy' },
{ text: 'eat this', author: 'Mom' }

Comment: @shilu then what if there is same number of authors?

Comment: @shilu ok then, please check my answer to your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could group by `author` and sort the keys by count and get a new array of objects.

```js
var array = [{ text: 'hi', author: 'Boy' }, { text: 'hola', author: 'Mom' }, { text: 'how are you', author: 'Boy' }, { text: 'I\'m good', author: 'Boy' }, { text: 'hello', author: 'Girl' }, { text: 'eat this', author: 'Mom' }, { text: 'Bye', author: 'Boy' }],
    temp = array.reduce((r, o) => {
        if (!r[o.author]) r[o.author] = [];
        r[o.author].push(o);
        return r;
    }, {}),
    result = Object
        .keys(temp)
        .sort((a, b) => temp[a].length - temp[b].length)
        .flatMap(k => temp[k]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you modify your dataset and add a count to it, the following code should do the job.

```
var data = [{ text: 'hi', author: 'Boy' },
{ text: 'hola', author: 'Mom' },
{ text: 'how are you', author: 'Boy' },
{ text: 'I\'m good', author: 'Boy' },
{ text: 'hello', author: 'Girl' },
{ text: 'eat this', author: 'Mom' },
{ text: 'Bye', author: 'Boy' }];

// add counts against each object
data.forEach(obj => {
  obj['count'] = data.filter((obj1) => obj1.author === 
    obj.author).length;
})

// user Array.sort function to sort your data
data.sort(function(a, b){
    if(a.count < b.count) return -1;
    if(a.count > b.count) return 1;
    return 0;
});
```

Although, it would be better if you get this list sorted from the backend.

Comment: @shilu Can you provide dataset you tested with?

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
array.sort((a, b) => {
  return a.author - b.author;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for this problem. You can use any property to sort this using this function.

```js
console.clear();
const data = [{ text: 'hi', author: 'Boy' },
{ text: 'hola', author: 'Mom' },
{ text: 'how are you', author: 'Boy' },
{ text: 'I\'m good', author: 'Boy' },
{ text: 'hello', author: 'Girl' },
{ text: 'eat this', author: 'Mom' },
{ text: 'Bye', author: 'Boy' }];

const sortBy = (value, data) => {
  let sortedData = [];
  const countValueObj = data.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    const authorValue = obj[value];
    if(!acc[authorValue]) acc[authorValue] = 1;
    else acc[authorValue]++;
    return acc;
  }, {})
  const countValueArr = Object.keys(countValueObj).sort((a, b) => countValueObj[a] - countValueObj[b]);
  countValueArr.forEach((val) => {
    const filteredData = data.filter((obj) => obj[value] === val);
    sortedData = [...sortedData, ...filteredData];
  })
  return sortedData;
}

const output = sortBy('author', data);

console.log(output)
```